# Creating a File of Function Definitions from Github

Tags: r, github

I am working with the R programming language. I was wondering - **without directly installing a library, is there a way to create a file that contains all the function definitions from the library?**

For example, suppose I want to install the following library from github: https://github.com/djvanderlaan/reclin

[image]

This gives me an option to download the library from github. If I click "download" (the green button), it brings me to this screen:

[image]

When I open the "R" folder, it shows me a list of (what I think are) different R functions required for this library:

[image]

If you open any of these files, this opens a R file containing the function definitions:

[image]

From here, is it possible to transfer all these functions definitions from the library into a single "list" - so that I can copy/paste them all at once into R studio, and then use functions from this library as if I had installed it?

I am using am older computer with only limited internet connection and no USB ports - I can not directly install any R libraries (I only have R with some preinstalled and basic libraries). I was hoping to make a list of all the functions from this library in a notepad file, and then send them to myself.

Thanks

Comment: Just copy/pasteing the functions is not the same as loading a proper package. Package code expects to be loaded into it's own namespace and have access to the functions declared in its dependencies and such. Plus many packages also have code that may require compiling to actually work. In particular that package you linked to has three cpp files in the src directory. That code simply would not work by just copying the files over.

Comment: thank you - in the past, I have been able to copy/paste function definitions and still got them to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `source("/path/to/function.R")` to load the functions from a single file, or apply `source()` over a list of files (see `list.files()`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not quite sure I understand - can you please show me what you mean?

Comment: You can use the source() function for one file, or if you have a folder of files you can source all of them with something like `list.files("/folder", full.names = TRUE) |> purrr::walk(source)` or `list.files("/folder", full.names = TRUE) |> lapply(source)`. (R4.1)